# add a column to the select query which could be null

Tags: sql-server

I would like to add another column to my select query called description inside posts table,
the problem is that this value could be null.
to make it clear, I have already linked foreign keys from tables Users, PostType and Votes.
Attaching the query:

```sql
SELECT po.id,
       po.title,
       CONVERT(varchar, po.pDate, 104) AS pDate,
       pt.type,
       us.userName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vt.isLike = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upvotes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vt.isLike = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downvotes
FROM Posts po
     INNER JOIN PostType pt ON po.typeId = pt.id
     INNER JOIN Users us ON po.userId = us.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Votes vt ON vt.postId = po.id
GROUP BY po.id,
         po.pDate,
         po.title,
         pt.type,
         us.userName;
```

How to avoid group by null?

Comment: *"How to avoid group by null?"* What do you mean by this?

Comment: You can't group by null. What to you mean?

Comment: if I'll add group by description as mentioned, the records will group the null values as one group and all other values as a separate group, therefore an error will return.

Comment: I want to avoid the null values group and instead group them separately.

Comment: is that possible?

Comment: So you you mean you want a group for rows where description has the value `NULL` and then a group for when it has a non-`NULL` value?

Comment: exactly, so it will show me all the information about each post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that column non-nullable on the fly. So in the SELECT clause just add one more column to display `CASE WHEN po.description IS NULL THEN 'present' ELSE 'absent' END AS description` and repeat it in the GROUP BY clause `CASE WHEN po.description IS NULL THEN 'present' ELSE 'absent' END`

```
SELECT po.id,
       po.title,
       CASE WHEN po.description IS NULL THEN 'present' ELSE 'absent' END AS description,
       CONVERT(varchar, po.pDate, 104) AS pDate,
       pt.type,
       us.userName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vt.isLike = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upvotes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vt.isLike = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downvotes
FROM Posts po
     INNER JOIN PostType pt ON po.typeId = pt.id
     INNER JOIN Users us ON po.userId = us.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Votes vt ON vt.postId = po.id
GROUP BY po.id,
         po.pDate,
         po.title,
         CASE WHEN po.description IS NULL THEN 'present' ELSE 'absent' END,
         pt.type,
         us.userName;
```

Comment: `IFNULL` isn't a function in T-SQL.

Comment: You are right. There is an equivalent for SQL Server. I've amended my answer.

Comment: I cant use IFNULL in sql server.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but I'm receiving an error:Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Why are you *still* using the `text` data type, @ShalevSror ? It was deprecated back in 2005.

Comment: I didn't know the column type... so, let's use CASE and IS NULL...

Comment: So you're saying it might be because I'm using text datatype? wait I will try with varchar

Comment: oh yes thank you so much, I changed the data type of description to varchar and it worked.